# demonstrate the continuity of a function

Tags: analysis

How can I demonstrate that if 
\[ g\colon\mathbb R\to \mathbb R, x \mapsto f(x) + \frac 12\arctan{\sqrt{x+1}}
\]
is constant, where
\[ f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R, x\mapsto \arctan(x+2) - \arctan x. \]

Comment: I TeXified your input, please check if I did correctly.

Comment: yes , it is :) , thank you

Comment: the question is constant

Comment: Simply derive, and find that $g'=0$.

Comment: Substitution $f$ in $g$ yields  $$g(x)=\arctan(x+2) - \arctan x+ \frac 12\arctan{\sqrt{x+1}},$$  so for verify if $f$ is constant, you may differentiate it, because composition $g\circ f$ is differetiable (prove this fact).

Comment: You have the wrong domain for $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not constant.

Differentiate to get $g'(x) = \frac{1}{(x+2)^2+1} - \frac{1}{x^2+1}+\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{x+1}(x+2)}$. $g'(0) = -\frac{27}{4}$, hence it is not constant.